# context(String) is undefined error while switch to webview mode in Appium Hybrid app testing

Tags: java, ios, webview, automation, appium

I have received error in Eclipse for

```
      driver.switchTo().context("WEBVIEW");
```

I am trying to switch the app into webview mode in hybrid ios application testing.
How to fix this error? I have attached screenshot below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems , this feature still to be implemented with Appium Java-Client.

Mean while please try with

```
 Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
    for (String contextName : contextNames) {
      System.out.println(contextName);
      if (contextName.contains("WEBVIEW")){
        driver.context(contextName);
      }
    }
```

***Note:***

Please use appium 1.0 Java-Client and create driver instance using AppiumDriver

e.g.

`public AppiumDriver driver=null;`

Comment: while trying this received the following errororg.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not implemented in this context, try switching into or out of a web view (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: I have modified my answer, please check with this, should work fine!

Comment: I used the same from link: https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/sample-code/examples/java/junit/src/test/java/com/saucelabs/appium/AndroidWebViewTest.java

But received the error or.openqa.selinium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser

Comment: I believe this should work, Given: you are using a Android 4.4+ device to test and automation mode is not Selendroid.

Also Please use AppiumDriver instead of RemoteWebDriver.

Comment: i am tryng with ios device! now it got working! have to refer the selenium standalone dependency 0.10 and java-client 1.2. Before that older version of dependency gives error.

Answer (score 0):

To use AppiumDriver context as for now, use Java-client-1.2 and selenium-standalone-1.10-dependencies

```
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
    for (String contextName : contextNames) {
      System.out.println(contextName);
      if (contextName.contains("WEBVIEW")){
        driver.context(contextName);
      }
    }
```

And this code is working. Thanks @Mfsi.AbhishekSwain

Comment: Using AppiumDriver is a quite different setup; in situations where it is necessary to use RemoteWebDriver, do you know of a way to switch contexts?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are using right version of selenium-remote-driver

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.42.2</version>
</dependency>
```